# file upload not working front end in october CMS

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

When I am adding `{% component 'fileUploader' %}` on front end it not working, as I can see in page view source of that page it seems related js and css file is not being added while it showing in admin and working fine in admin section.
Is there any other process add upload files from front end?
I fallowed https://octobercms.com/plugin/responsiv-uploader this url instruction but it doesn't working.

Comment: what is not working ? can you specify any error in log or somewhere please

Comment: how about framework extras ? have you added in your template ? i guess its required at times to be able to make some plugins work.. so make sure that too. - https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction#framework-script

Comment: What model and what relationship and attribute you want to use the Uploader for? This is important because you can only use models with a relationship (eg. HasMany) with ```System\Models\File```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to initialize the componet before you use it.
You can do this by dragging the component to the page or layout in the backend.

Or you can add the code to the top of the page or layout source. In you case it might look something like this: `[fileUploader]`

More info in the [docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#introduction)

Comment: I added below code on top same page but it's not working
 [fileUploader]
maxSize = "2"
fileTypes = "*"

Answer (score 0):

The file Uploader plugin is a 'developer tool' as stated by the author. It must be specifically configured to make use of a (already existing) model relationship with `System\Models\File`.

How to make this relationship is described here in the OC docs: http://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments

Example of a single file attachment:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'avatar' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```